# How do I set the pagination to occur after X rows with a JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want the detail band not to draw more than X rows. I tried setting up the ***`splitType`*** to **`Immediate`** or **`Prevent`** but nothing changed. How can I tell `JasperReports` to paginate only after X number of results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't get a good answer and have options beyond your current implementation, you could look at [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) as an option.  You can report subsets of data easily enough and can conditionally include or exclude page breaks.